# How startupdatinglocation and stopupdatinglocation on start stop buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have two buttons "start" and "stop" and defined "didUpdateToLocation" delegate method from CLLocationManager class.

when i click on start button with single line code like

```
-(void)act_start{[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];}
```

and when i click on stop button. with single line code like

```
-(void)act_stop{[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];}
```

It is working fine.

But my problem is when i click on start button 2 times and after i click on stop button then "didUpdateToLocation" not get stopped. I do not understand how can i stop "didUpdateToLocation" method.